# How to store fetch response in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, fetch

sorry for the basic question.
I was trying using fetch to get data from api and want to store that response into a javascript variable but its not working as I have expected
My code-

```
async function fun() {
    var a = "initial";
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            a = data;
            console.log(a);
        })

    await console.log("Response => ", a);
}
```

Output - Response => initial

What is the correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 5):

You may need to add `await` before `fetch`.

```js
async function fun() {
  var a = "initial";
  await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      a = data;
      console.log(a);
    })

  console.log("Response => ", a);
}
```

Comment: Although technically correct, don't do this. This ain't good code. At least get rid of that nasty second `then`. like `var a = await fetch(...).then(res => res.json());`

Answer (score 5):

You are doing more than you need to.  Your fetch call should be returning the promise.  Then when you want to access the data, you `await` the `fun` call, and can read the response

```js
async function fun() {
  return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then(res => res.json());
}

const data  = await fun();
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to just use `async/await` you could do something like

```js
const fun = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
  return response.json()
}

await fun();
```

Comment: Both of these give me the error: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: You probably have something else going on there.  As you can see, both of these functions are using the async keyword.  Are you forgetting that part?

Comment: The await that is outside the function, still gives a SyntaxError.

Answer (score 0):

```
let darth = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
let java = []
darth.then(res => res.json()).then((log) => java.push(log))
const user = java.flat().map(res => res)
```

This works on developer console on the chrome but not on visual studio code. Strange. I was able to fetch the data and put it into a const